# Startup RealVNC delayed when monitor is not physically connected

Tags: boot, monitor, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a setup composed by a raspberry PI zero W and it is configured to provide a SSID. I'm using it without monitor and keyboard, just with VNC and I'm using RealVNC.
Well, it works fine, the only (but quite annoying..) issue is that when the monitor is physically connected the VNC client can connect immediately after boot, when the monitor is not connected it works but after a kind of delay of 6 minutes more or less. After this time the connection could be established perfectly. Can you tell me why it happens? It seems a kind of timeout waiting the monitor.. but where it's configured in case? any other idea?

My config.txt:

```
dtparam=audio=on
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
gpu_mem=256

max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
# hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
start_x=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=230779

In my case it worked fine!